# How to fix jQuery UI dialog size during dragging?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

It was a simple dialog as below code, its height is reduced whenever the dialog is being dragged. Its height value is even changed when I set dialog's resizable = false. Finally I fixed it by re-update dialog height in dragStop event handler.

I found a similar issue had been reported [here](http://extremedev.blogspot.com/2011/10/jquery-dialog-height-problem.html), but it was with IE and the author suggested to not set height value, that IMHO is not suitable for all usecases.

I'm using Chrome and jQuery UI 1.8.19

```
<p><a id="edit" href="#">Open Editor</a></p>
<div id="editor"></div>

$(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("#edit").on("click", function ()
        {
                var $dialog = $("#editor")
                .dialog(
                {
                    title: "HTML Editor",
                    modal: true,
                    autoOpen: false,
                    width: 600,
                    height: 350,
                    minWidth: 300,
                    minHeight: 200,
                    closeOnEscape: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    open: function ()
                    {
                    },
                    buttons:
                    {
                        "Save": function ()
                        {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        },
                        "Cancel": function ()
                        {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    },
                    dragStop: function (e, ui)
                    {
                        $(this).dialog("option", "height", "377px");
                    }
                });
            }

            $dialog.dialog("open");
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Update 1: I just created a new project (ASP.NET MVC 4) and found that problem happened when I used following CSS rule, why?

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Comment: Make sure you check all the places where you're setting the height. I had a similar problem a few weeks back, and the only way i could get around it was code clean-up. Check all the places where you're setting the height and probably commenting and debugging with each may make you realize where setting the height is actually needed. Time consuming, but will result in cleaner code.

Comment: I faced another size issue with jQuery UI's resizable yesterday, it seems that jQuery/UI always calculate elements' width and height wrongly if you use box-sizing is border-box. Doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery 1.8 finally understand box-sizing thoroughly and we no longer need tweaking it :)

[Documentation](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/16/jquery-1-8-box-sizing-width-csswidth-and-outerwidth/)

Answer (score 3):

jQuery calculates dialog size incorrectly when using box-sizing: border-box (with default template). I fixed by store dialog's height in the open event and manually set dialog height in dragStart/dragStop events:

```
                    dragStart: function (e, ui)
                    {
                        $(this).parent().height(height);
                    },
                    dragStop: function (e, ui)
                    {
                        $(this).parent().height(height);
                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it fixed by using simple css:

```
 .ui-dialog {
              height:auto !important;
            }
```

Comment: I had a slightly different issue for which I have found no answers.  My dialog boxes did automatically size to fit it's contents, except after it had been dragged, then the width and height would be locked.  This style seems to have fixed that.  I also added `width: auto !important;`, though.